# Angular 5 - Unable to navigate from one component to another component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngroute

I'm developing Angular application. In that I've two pages login and home. After login submit button it should navigate to home page. For this I tried multiple ways but it is not navigating to home page. Finally I used `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in my login(app.component.html) file. So home page is displaying in login page. I want to navigate home page after login. Below is my current output and code

[image]

And when I'm refreshing `http://localhost:4200/home` it is showing errorlike below

[image]

app.component.html (login page)

```
<div align="center">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onLoginSubmit()" class="fullForm">

        <div class="imgcontainer"></div>
        <h2>PL Auth</h2>
        <div class="container">
            <form (ngSubmit)="generateOtpSubmit()" class="generateOtpForm">
                <label> <b>Username: </b>
                </label> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" id="username"
                    [(ngModel)]=userName name="uname" required> <br> <br>
                <label> <b>Password : </b>
                </label> <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password"
                    [(ngModel)]=password name="psw" required> <br> <br>
                <button type="submit" class="otpButton">Generate OTP</button>
            </form>
            <br> <br> <label> <b>Enter OTP : </b>
            </label> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter OTP" id="otp" [(ngModel)]=otp
                name="otp" required> <br> <br>
            <button type="submit" class="loginButton">Login</button>

        </div>
        <div>
            <p style="color: red;">{{ loginStatus }}</p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {  RouterModule, Routes   } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
//import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Text } from '@angular/compiler';


export const appRoutes: Routes = [
   {path: 'home', component:HomepageComponent}
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  otpsubmitted = false;
  loginSubmitted = false;
  userName = '';
  password = '';
  otp ='';
  userAuthCheck:Text;
  checkOtp:Text;
  authCheck ='';
  loginStatus='';

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  constructor(private http: Http,private httpClient: HttpClient,private route: Router ) { }

  private generateOtp(){
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/loginController/generateotp', {
      userMail: this.userName
    })
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
        },
        err => {
          console.log("Error occured");
        }
      );
  }

  private logSubmit(){
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/loginController/authUser', {
      userMail: this.userName,
      password: this.password,
      otp: this.otp
    })
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          const printResp=res.json();
          console.log(res);
          //this.loginStatus=printResp.status;

          if (printResp.status === 'true'){
            this.loginStatus =  '';
            console.log('in the clickName');
            this.route.navigateByUrl('/home');
            //this.route.navigate(['home/']);
          } else if(printResp.status === 'false') {
                this.loginStatus =  printResp.Data.errorMessage;                          
          }
           },
        err => {
          console.log("Error occured"+err);
        }
      );
  }


  generateOtpSubmit() {
    this.otpsubmitted = true;
    this.generateOtp();
  }

  onLoginSubmit(){
    this.loginSubmitted = true;
    this.logSubmit();
  }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import {ApplicationComponent} from './application/application.component';
import {NavigationComponent} from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomepageComponent},
  {path: 'application', component: ApplicationComponent},
  {path: 'navigation', component: NavigationComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule,RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { ApplicationComponent } from './application/application.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { SearchuserComponent } from './searchuser/searchuser.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomepageComponent,
    ApplicationComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    SearchuserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

homepage.component.html

```
<p>
  homepage works!
</p>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CyberSecurityVw</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

homepage.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.css']
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: You mentionned a 404 error for a server request in one of your comments below. Did you investgate that ? For which request is it?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
this.route.navigate(['/home']);
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: can you post home.component.ts file

Comment: posted home.comonent.ts

Comment: Do you have the template in the folder

Comment: yes I have that template In the question mistakenly I named it as home.component.html. I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

First :you will need to move your login form to a new component called (login)

second :your app component html should hold only this line

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

because app component will act like your landing page so you shouldn't add login form on it

Third : you need to modify your routing

```
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'home', component: HomepageComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: '/example', pathMatch: 'full' },
            {
                path: 'example', component: ExampleComponent
            }
        ]
    },

    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    declarations: []
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

-what will happen is when u type your website url without any routing it will navigate to home/example - so home component should contain your website design template so all children component will inject within home component and take the same template design

-login component is stand alone because u don't need it to take the same website design template

Fourth : in your home page html add this

```
<div>
   //your header 
     <header></header>
      <div class="content">
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     </div>
    // your footer
    <footer></footer>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First add import in your main component

```
import {Router } from '@angular/router';
```

In the same file add below code for constructor and method

```
constructor(private route: Router) {}
public Dashbord()
{
  this.route.navigate(['/dashboard']);
}
```

In `app-routing.module.ts` file add `dashboard`

```
const routes: Routes =
[
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full' ,component: TestComponent},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent } 
];
```

This is your `.html` file code

```
<button mat-button (click)="Dashbord()">Dashboard</button><br>
```

Good luck.